# No puedo hacer push a GitHub

Tags: git, github

tengo un inconveniente con git, deseo hacer un push a un proyecto grupal, sin embargo, no me permite hacerlo, si lo hago a través de https me arroja un error 403 y si lo hago por ssh, me parece "Permission denied(publikey)" asimismo, ya tengo agregada la llave ssh en la cuenta de git, aun asi, no puedo hacer push, solo puedo clonar via hhtps, ni siquiera via ssh.

Espero su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Estas trabajando en windows? Ese es el mensaje de error completo, o dice algo mas?

Comment: Revisa bien la URL del repositorio para verificar que es tuyo. Pudiera ser que estés intentado acceder a una copia del repositorio de alguno de tus compañeros, con lo que obviamente ni la contraseña (para https) ni la publickey (para ssh) funcionarían.

Comment: Si, estoy en windows, es una cuenta que hemos creado, todos tenemos acceso, asi que estoy tratando de acceder al repositorio correcto, incluso cree un nuevo repositorio remoto y no me permite hacer push, talvez, es un error con mi pc o configuracion de la llave? no se me genera el id_rsa, por mas, que lo estoy haciendo segun manual y videos, hace tiempo si pude hacer commmit y push.. no se que sucede ahora. cuando quiero hacer push con ssh, me sale este error que tratan en el post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335197/gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user#answer-40907049

Comment: Es difícil aventurar hipótesis, pero... Entiendo que el repositorio lo ha creado uno del equipo y lo ha compartido con los demás, pero que cada miembro del equipo tiene su cuenta separada en Github (otra opción sería que todos compartierais una única cuenta y contraseña, lo que no es en absoluto recomendable). Es posible que a la hora de compartir el repositorio su creador os haya dado permisos de lectura, pero no de escritura, con lo que podríais hacer `clone` y `pull`, pero no `push`.

Comment: También es posible que tú tengas más de una cuenta (usuario) en Github, y que estés intentando acceder a una cuenta con la pubkey de la otra. Sería más fácil si trabajaras en Windows, pues podrías intentar hacer un `ssh` a `git@github.com` y ver qué usuario es el que accede. Quizás desde Git Bash en windows también pueda intentarse. Mira a ver.

Comment: Como dijo @abulafia, prueba haciendo `ssh git@github.com -vvv` y revisa qué llaves está intentando usar. Probablemente tienes llaves existentes como `id_rsa` o `identity`  que se envían primero. Para cuando envía la correcta ya has hecho muchos intentos y github te rechaza. Si estuvieras en linux es trivial reparar eso en `~/.ssh/config` pero no estoy seguro de dónde se almacenan las llaves en windows

Answer (score -1):

Primero verifica lo siguinete:

1. Que hayas configurado `git` correctamente desde tu consola. Para ello ve a la ruta `c/usuarios/tucuentadered/` y revisa el archivo `.gitconfig` en el deberias tener algo asi.

   ```
   [user]
       name = Tu Nombre
       email = Tu correo
   ```

   El `name` debe ser el mismo con el que creaste tu cuenta en github p gitlab y el proveedor que sea. El `email` lo mismo que el anterior, debe ser exactamente el mismo.
2. Verifica que Windows tenga las credenciales de acceso a tu proveedor de git (github, gitlab u otro). Para ello ve inicio, en el buscador escribe 'administrador de credenciales' en el apartado Credenciales de Windows verifica que aparezca el dominio de tu proveedor junto con las credenciales de tu cuenta.

Me dices como te va con eso.